# Print the result of a basic HTTP GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I want to do a little javascript library that contains one method that return the content of this page via GET METHOD: http://www.olivettom.com/test/test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFromPage(){
    var result = ?????
    return result;   
}   

var result =getFromPage()   
//should print "result=key:value"
alert("result="+result);
</script>
```

I tried a lot of things including ajax, but I ended with a cross domain exception.
How can I implement this method?

Comment: There are many questions that address cross-domain AJAX. None of them answered your question?

Comment: My question is more isn't it a simplier answer than Ajax and Cross Domain.

Comment: And I do a Get, Not a POST

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use GET or POST. They're both AJAX, and cross-domain is prohibited by default.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-domain for many questions that address this